# When running ajax with cron its not executing the PHP file where I need to save the data

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, cron

I am trying to save data into MySQL using file add.php through ajax. I am getting data through cron.php. Data is saved when I am running cron.php file in browser but it's not saved when am running through cron job.

Here is my code:

cron.php

```
  $.ajax({
              method: 'POST',
              url:    'add.php',
               data: { id: id, videoid: vids }
               })
              .done(function(data) {   
                          });
```

add.php
  am inserting id and videoid in the database.
Can anyone help me to insert data using cron with ajax and php

Comment: When you call a php script from the command line, you just get the output and the javascript in it is not executed. So for cron you need a php script that does not rely on ajax / javascript.

Comment: I am interested in understanding the useful combination of ajax (a UI-oriented architecture) and cron (an non-UI-oriented architecture). What am I missing

Comment: tyhen how i can i execute am passing values through ajax and javascript

Comment: No you're not. Not when you are using php from the command line / cron.

Answer (score 0):

Ajax is a front end thing while cron job is a pure server back-end thing.
Instead of ajax you should make a function similiar to what is in add.php or call it from your cron.php passing arguments to it.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to send data to add.php through POST, you can use CURL in cron.php instead of your jQuery code.

Another solution would be to send the data to add.php directly using GET parameters (instead of POST).

Comment: can you give me sample of curl I have not much idea about it

Comment: //set POST variables
$url = 'http://example.com/add.php';

$fields = array(
 'id' => $id,
 'videoid' => $videoId
);

//url-ify the data for the POST
foreach($fields as $key=>$value) { $fields_string .= $key.'='.$value.'&'; }
rtrim($fields_string, '&');

//open connection
$ch = curl_init();

//set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, count($fields));
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string);

//execute post
$result = curl_exec($ch);

//close connection
curl_close($ch);